# IF function in combination with an Round function Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, syntax, rounding

I'm trying to combine an `IF` function with an round function to try to round a certain value.
In this case the value is in cell H2. E2=decimal places. So if `E2=9` there are `9` decimal places. I try to use this formula but it doesn't work(just based on `E2=0` and `E2=1`).

```
=IF( E2= 0,ROUND( $H2, 2),IF( E2=1 ,ROUND( $H2, 1))
```

I get an error, something is wrong in the syntax can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether it is a language setting, but I needed to replace all ',' by ';'. Further you missed a closing bracked.

```
=IF(E2=0;ROUND($H2;2);IF(E2=1;ROUND($H2;1)))
```

Besides this, I think that

```
=IFERROR(ROUND($H$2;E2); 0)
```

would be a better solution to use. Now you don't need the IF functions.

Comment: Ah thanks :). I missed the closing bracket, sometimes you just oversee the smallest of things!